# ajax и checkbox

Tags: php, html, ajax

Есть отдельный input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like-1" name="like_status">
<label for="like-1" id="var">
```

Как написать скрипт, который по нажатию передавал бы данные id методом POST в php файл 'somefile.php'. Я знаю, что надо использовать ajax, но не могу подключить так, чтобы в файле 'likes.php' отображался массив POST и отправленными данными.

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST["var"]);

if(isset($_POST)){
  echo "данные пришли";
}

?>
```

Сам скрипт ниже:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like-1").bind("click", function(event){
    $.ajax({
      url:"likes.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:{"var":$("#var").html()},
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(result) {
        alert("Данные пришли");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81555/discussion-on-question-by-more7ti-ajax--checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like-1" name="like_status">
<label for="like-1" id ="var">102</label>
```

js:

```
           $.ajax({
                url:"likes.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{"var":$("#var").html()},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(result) {
                    alert("Данные пришли");                                         
                },
            });
```

> И выставьте в конце "каждой строки" `;`, у вас не везде. 
>   На стороне likes.php ловятся так: `$_POST["var"];`

Comment: на стороне likes.php пустой массив POST

Comment: @more7ti обмновите код html,js и php покажите как в данный момент, после исправления.

Comment: готово.массив post отображается как NULL, хотя данные пришли(если судить по if

Comment: @Total Pusher то что я имел в виду, то я и написал. Я отвечал на поставленный вопрос так, как его задали. Html() возвращает то, что заключено между тегами (нам это и нужно). Какие ещё ко мне вопросы?

Comment: в консоли показывается что данные приходят, но сам файл не подхватывает эти данные.почему?